# How to make a WPF DataGrid display a ViewModel collection with binding and a DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, datatemplate, observablecollection

First off, an apology as I am sure this is question's answer is quite simple.  Nonetheless I still cannot seem to find an answer.

This is my first week using WPF.  I simply wish to display the contents of some sort of list inside of a DataGrid.  I am currently trying to use an ObservableCollection<> and a DataGrid, but that can change.  How do I DataTemplate the list and display it?

The list is in a ViewModel, which has been set in Apps.xaml.cs as the DataSource for the MainWindow.xaml:

```cs
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    var window = new MainWindow();

    // Create the ViewModel to which 
    // the main window binds.
    var viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();

    // Allow all controls in the window to 
    // bind to the ViewModel by setting the 
    // DataContext, which propagates down 
    // the element tree.
    window.DataContext = viewModel;

    window.Show();
}
```

Here is the current list:

```cs
    public ObservableCollection<PersonData> SearchResults { get; set; }
```

As for my xaml, though, I am rather lost -- I've tried fiddling around with binding and ItemsSource, and really have no idea how to use them here.  Also, I suppose using a DataTemplate will be necessary, as I need to let it know somehow that the columns need to display certain properties of the PersonData, such as first and last name, location, and title.  Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

More generally -- how does one simply display a ViewModel list, collection, what have you, period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ach.  Failure to pre-study is fatal -- I did not implement INotifyPropertyChanged.  Found out how to here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695

Answer (score 12):

Your basic `DataGrid` syntax should look something like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name"  Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

If you don't want to display your data in a `DataGrid`, you can use an [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx).

The default `ItemsControl` will add all your items to a `StackPanel`, and draw each of them using a `TextBlock` bound to the `.ToString()` of the item. You can change how the `ItemsControl` displays the items by specifying your own `ItemsPanelTemplate` and `ItemTemplate` for it to use. For some examples, check out [my blog post on WPF's ItemsControl](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/).

Comment: Thanks, but it seems my program is determined to hate me.  I went ahead and tried simplifying by converting the search results to a collection of strings as on your blog, and I used the first ItemsControl example there; nothing shows.

Comment: @NathanBond It sounds like the `DataContext` is not set correctly then, or your `SearchResults` collection is not raising a `PropertyChanged` notification. I'd recommend the tool [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to help debug the problem

Comment: yes, I found I had forgotten to include the INotifiyPropertyChanged interface.  Thank you for your help.